# Select cashiers who sold tickets for different events in the same day

Tags: mysql

I have next table :

```
CREATE TABLE sales
( id            INT    ( 10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  event_name    VARCHAR( 99),
  cashier_name  VARCHAR( 99),
  sale_date     VARCHAR( 99),
  sale_time     VARCHAR( 99)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

And next data (query included for someone to test) :

```
ID  EVENT_NAME        CASHIER_NAME  SALE_DATE    SALE_TIME
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Metallico 8pm     Jenny         2022-03-11   15:37
2   Metallico 8pm     Sandy         2022-03-11   16:01
3   Red Puppets 10am  Jenny         2022-03-08   09:40
4   Red Puppets 10am  Jenny         2022-03-11   08:55
5   Wild Cats 8pm     Sandy         2022-02-25   19:13
6   Wild Cats 8pm     Jenny         2022-02-25   16:59

INSERT INTO sales (id, event_name, cashier_name, sale_date, sale_time)
           VALUES (1, 'Metallico 8pm',   'Jenny', '2022-03-11', '15:37'),
                  (2, 'Metallico 8pm',   'Sandy', '2022-03-11', '16:01'),
                  (3, 'Red Puppets 10am','Jenny', '2022-03-08', '09:40'),
                  (4, 'Red Puppets 10am','Jenny', '2022-03-11', '08:55'),
                  (5, 'Wild Cats 8pm',   'Sandy', '2022-02-25', '19:13'),
                  (6, 'Wild Cats 8pm',   'Jenny', '2022-02-25', '16:59')
```

As the title says, I need to get **JENNY** because she has sales for *different* events in the *same* day (1,4), Sandy also has sales for *different* events but dates are *different* (2,5).

Next query gives me the events (3 records) but I'm not sure how to include the condition `with sales in the same day` :

```
  SELECT *
    FROM sales
GROUP BY event_name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If I change the `GROUP BY` I get Jenny and Sandy (2 records) but not sure how to exclude Sandy :

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
GROUP BY sale_date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

(And no, this is not *homework*, I work at a museum with a small theater inside for children plays, concerts and contests, we are having "issues" with cashiers and money and we are trying to cross some data to catch the problem.)

Comment: select event_name, count(*) as total, cashier_name from sales where sale_date = '2022-03-11' group by cashier_name having total > 1;

Comment: @user2260040, thanks but we don't know the date.

Comment: that is a bad query and should give an error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=060864b914280b19acc03937cefd573c

Comment: @nbk, it works in mysql (WAMP) 

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez then enable full_group_By, then you will be forced to write clear comands

Comment: select cashier_name, sale_date, count(*) as total from sales group by cashier_name, sale_date having total > 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select CASHIER_NAME
from sales
group by cashier_name,sale_date
having COUNT( distinct event_name) >1 ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=deb0b301a2a0a2263285710bba9203ce)

All what you need is `group by cashier_name,sale_date` and  `having COUNT( distinct event_name) >1 ;`

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to correlate using *exists*

```
select distinct cashier_name 
from sales s
where exists (
  select * from sales s2 
  where s2.cashier_name = s.cashier_name 
    and s2.sale_date = s.sale_date 
    and s2.event_name != s.event_name
);
```